# Change date format in JOptionPane for Java

Tags: java, joptionpane

I know there are some answers to this question but I am still confused.
The question comes straight out of my assignment.

Write a program that reads a `String` for a `date` in the format `month/day/year` and displays it in the format `day.month.year`, which is a typical format used in `Europe`. For example, if the input is `06/17/11`, the output should be `17.06.11.` Your program should use `JOptionPane` for input and output."

Please help!

Greetings
Evert

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` `MM/dd/yy` -> `MM.dd.yy`

Comment: Sounds like homework ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You will need 2 DateFormats. One for the inputFormat and one for the output format. The inputFormat parses the input and creates an Date Object, which can be used by the outputFormat to create a String representing the format:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Date in Form MM/dd/yy");

DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, formattedDate);
```